# Android Apps Testing

Tags: android

I am new to android apps testing. I have downloaded a free android apps (.apk file) and like to test that android application.

What I did, I have installed that **.apk** file in command prompt using this cmd
**" adb install .apk "** File got installed then I have tested the app in an emulator.

But I want to know how to do all kinds of testing for an android application Or otherwise what and all basic testing we need to know when we are going to test an android application.

Suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the Android Developers site [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/testing/testing_android.html) for "How to test `android` Applications". First you have to know the [tools](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidTesting/article.html) of `testing` and how the testing structure would be...

Comment: I will go through the links provided by you for basic understanding for sure.Thanks for that. One more query like if we just have an .apk file can we still do all kinds of testing?

Comment: apk file is sufficient if u r good at preparing test cases... r u can prepare sample test projects as said in above link and get complete idea on that...

Comment: sure. Will start with learning sample test project. Thanks for your valuable time in giving me all the details.

Comment: as u r new to StackOverflow pls follow this link to know more about this site...http://stackoverflow.com/about this helps u in posting/answering questions effectively...

Comment: The mocking framework *Mockito* now works with Android too. Investigate using that for you unit tests. Love those lads @Square

http://corner.squareup.com/2012/10/mockito-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a service like AWS Device Farm, Firebase, or Nativetap. FULL DISCLOSURE - I work with [Nativetap](http://nativetap.io).

All of the services mentioned above allow you to perform testing on Android devices remotely, while only Nativetap allows you to perform that testing with multitouch support, screenshots, screenrecording, performance tracking, etc.

I encourage you to signup for a free account and explore how Nativetap can help you in your app testing.